# Stream ending unexpectedly when doing a multipart form-data request

Tags: java, c#, rest, ms-office, vsto

So we have a server app written in java and it has a rest service to which you can upload files in the form of a multipart request. This is the signature of the method

```
@POST
@Transactional(TxType.REQUIRED)
@Path("/{id}")
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
public ContentInfo uploadToInstanceFromMultipart(UploadRequest uploadRequest, @PathParam(JsonKeys.ID) String id) {
```

As you can see thre is nothing special about it, just a post service. However on the other side we are writing an ms office plugin (VSTO) that sends a file to that service using RestSharp.

```
  void Application_DocumentBeforeSave(Word.Document Doc, ref bool SaveAsUI, ref bool Cancel)
    {
        var client = new RestClient("...");
        client.Authenticator = new HttpBasicAuthenticator(...);
        var request = new RestRequest("api/content/{id}", Method.POST);
        var name = Doc.Name;
        var contentId = getContentId(name);
        var fileName = getName(name);

        request.AddUrlSegment("id", contentId); 
        request.AddFile(fileN, Doc.Path + "\\" + Doc.Name, "application/msword");

        IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
        var content = response.Content;
        MessageBox.Show(content);
```

And i don't see anything special in here too but when saving the file (thus sending it to the server), the server responds with the following exception

```
(default task-33) Generic exception: javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException: Processing of multipart/form-data request failed. Stream ended unexpectedly
```

And boils down to

```
Caused by: org.apache.commons.fileupload.MultipartStream$MalformedStreamException: Stream ended unexpectedly
at org.apache.commons.fileupload.MultipartStream$ItemInputStream.makeAvailable(MultipartStream.java:1005)
at org.apache.commons.fileupload.MultipartStream$ItemInputStream.read(MultipartStream.java:903)
at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:133)
at org.apache.commons.fileupload.util.LimitedInputStream.read(LimitedInputStream.java:134)
at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:107)
at org.apache.commons.fileupload.util.Streams.copy(Streams.java:100)
at org.apache.commons.fileupload.util.Streams.copy(Streams.java:70)
at org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadBase.parseRequest(FileUploadBase.java:347)
... 70 more
```

Any ideas what is going on with the request?

Comment: Any news on this topic?

Comment: I'm sorry for the late answer and yes. As it turns out our application (on the server side) didn't take into account the new size of the document so it closed the stream before reading the entire document. Say if we downloaded a document, added some new information and tried uploading it back, it failed because it tried reading less bytes. This bug was reproduced only with new data (say new text). If we downloaded it and uploaded it without modifying the file it was fine.